# How to architect event notification with Spring Framework

Tags: spring, events, architecture, spring-cloud

I need event-notification engine for my microservice product.

For example:

**Abstract:** an application "A" on node "A-7" sends an asynchronous task to an application "B". The application "B" on random node (e. g. "B-3") recieves the asynchronous task, process it, stores the task result. The application "A" knows how to get the task result, but don't know when.

**Problem:** the application "B" shall notify the application "A" on node "A-7" (not other nodes, but "A-7" only) that task is ready. The application "A" must recieve the notification immediately (i. e. with low latency).

I can use Spring Boot, Apache Kafka, Apache Zookeeper and PostgreSQL for solution.

Is there library/solution that solves my problem? I think it is common problem. I read the Spring and Spring Cloud documentation but didn't find any solution.

Comment: What's the reason for A-7 should only get the notifications, not the other nodes?

Comment: @sonus21 because it interacts with user. The user clicks a button, the application "A" starts a task. The user can wait till end of process. In this case the user will get result as soon as the result will be ready. There is ws-socket connection between the application and the user.

Comment: is that a transient state? It seems to me you don't care even though if a request fails.

Comment: in my idea when the task has been done application B should send a message to a particular topic in kafka. when application A consumes that message it understands that task has been done.